# How do you order the calendar widgets of bootstrap daterangepicker rails after collapse?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

I'm using the bootstrap-daterangepicker-rails gem by Dan Grossman, Jordan Brock . I noticed that when the two calendars are collapsed using bootstrap for a phone-size screen, that the "from" calendar falls below the "to" calendar. Is this an issue for anyone else. Is there a way to reorder this, or do I need to select a different range-picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was posted and answered on github under the "issues" section.https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker/issues/225. There are various code updates recommended to correct the issue, but the work-around acceptable for my application was to set the "opens: left" option.